# Is it possible to get local feature importances using MDI or permutation importance with a RF or ET?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

When finding feature importances for a classification task using, for example, `RandomForestClassifier` or `ExtraTreesClassifier`, is it possible to get local feature importances. Say we have 10 classes to predict, we can easily retrieve the global importance, but is there a way to get which features are important for say class 1,...,10 individually?

I understand this can be done with `shap`, just checking if we can do it with impurity (MDI) and permutation (MDA) methods.

Comment: You can try one vs rest and see what is important on a per class basis

Comment: Okay, so we do this, `OneVsRestClassifier(model)`, and we would have to loop through this n class times? Is there a way to specify which class is `One` and not `the Rest`?